# ARCore Replacing Andy object

Tags: unity-game-engine, arcore

When I try to replace the Andy object in Unity with a model I made in C4D it doesn't spawn. Do I have to prepare the object in some way so it will spawn the right way?

Sometimes it gets spawned but not on the anchor I tapped on. It's somewhere in the space floating and when I try to approach it, it disappears or shifts place.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Are you sure the pivot of your object is at its center? Did you try any other objects to see if it works?

Comment: Just a suggetion .First you Update ARcore and Unity to latest version.Just a suggetion .First you Update ARcore and Unity to latest version.First open GoogleARCore/Examples/HelloAR
Open the scene .
Click Example Controller.In the Inspector window drag and drop the model in Andy Android Prefab.
Now take the build in unity(Android platform) and test it on a AR-supported  android device.
Run the application.It will search for a plane.

Answer (score 0):

1. First you Update ARcore and Unity to latest version.
2. Open GoogleARCore/Examples/HelloAR
3. Open the scene.
4. Click Example Controller.
5. In the Inspector window drag and drop the model in Andy Android
   Prefab.
6. Now take the build in unity(Android platform) and test it on a
   AR-supported android device.
7. Run the application.It will search for a plane.
8. Once the plane is detected touch on the screen to place the model.